# React Router - render two components under one route / enable child component to still access params?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux

My React Router thingy looks like this:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path='/posts/:id' component={PostsView} />
  <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
  <Route component={NotFound}/>
</Switch>
```

I would now like to implement an AudioPlayer and show it on the same page.

I could of course just import the `AudioPlayer` in the `PostsView` and render it from there. However, I think it would be nicer and more pure to not mix the two components, but have them next to another in a third component which renders both of them and is only responsible for showing stuff on the screen.

I tried to do that, but I got stuck, since my Posts Component needs the route `/posts/:id`, so I could not just put it in a third component. I tried something like this:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path='/sentences/:id' component={Main} />
  <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
  <Route component={NotFound}/>
</Switch>
```

and then in `Main` I tried:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <PostsView />
        <AudioPlayer />
      </div>
      );
  }
```

... but this seems to be the wrong approach, since things go wrong with react router then! What would be the most sensible approach to combine the two components, and keep my routing intact?

Answer (score 0):

If the audioplayer is something that is shown globally, and plays *something* that's not always relevant to what's being displayed currently in the app, you might want to consider moving that *something* to a global store like redux. When you select something to be played, you would update `redux` with an action, and inside `AudioPlayer`, you would listen for changes in the store and adjust accordingly.

```
import { setCurrentlyPlaying } from "actions"

class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  onClickTrack = (track) => {
    this.props.setCurrentlyPlaying(track)
  }
}

export default connect(null, { setCurrentlyPlaying })(SomeComponent)
```

this random component sets the currently playing track via redux - you can also adjust your action to, say, add to a playlist, etc.

In audioplayer

```
class AudioPlayer extends React.Component {
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const nextTrack = nextProps.track
    const currentTrack = this.props.track

    if (nextTrack !== currentTrack) {
      // do something
    }
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    const nextTrack = nextProps.track
    const currentTrack = this.props.track

    if (nextTrack !== currentTrack) {
      // do something
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (<audio src={this.props.track.src}/>)
  }
}

export default connect(
  (state) => {
    return { track: state.currentlyPlaying }
  }
)(AudioPlayer)
```

you can do it a number of ways. I'm not sure how the `audio` element will react to re-renders (I've never used the element myself), so you might have to implement `shouldComponentUpdate` and make sure you're not updating the component unless you need to.

Doing this, you would have a global "container" which would display `AudioPlayer` and React Router.

```
<div>
  <Switch>...</Switch>
  <AudioPlayer/>
</div>
```

edit, you don't need `redux` if you either a) don't mind passing down a callback to set the track to be played and maintaining this track in a common parent.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  state = { currentlyPlaying: null }

  setCurrentlyPlaying = (track) => {
    this.setState({ currentlyPlaying: track })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child setCurrentlyPlaying={this.setCurrentlyPlaying}/>
        <AudioPlayer currentlyPlaying={this.state.currentlyPlaying}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

or b) use `context` to provide a callback - i would not recommend doing it this way as even React's maintainers recommend against using context. I'm not as familiar with context, so if you want to do it this way, you'll need to look up how to do it.